# Java Exception java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException

Tags: java, multithreading, anonymous-class

In Java, I am getting this Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Unknown Source)
    at Threads4.go(Threads4.java:14)
    at Threads4.main(Threads4.java:4)
```

Here is the code:

```
public class Threads4 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Threads4().go();
    }
    void go(){
        Runnable r = new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                System.out.println("foo");
            }
        };
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
        t.start();

    }
}
```

What does the exception mean?

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to start the thread twice.

Comment: looking at the other answers from the same minute, do we have a race condition here :) ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot start your thread twice.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot start your thread twice,

```
t.start();
t.start();
```

you are trying to start something which is already started, so you getting `IllegalThreadStateException`

Comment: How is this different from the previous two answers?

Comment: and how is the reason supposed to be different for a common issue

Answer (score 0):

You can't start the same Thread twice.

Create another Thread, e.g.

```
Thread thread2 = new Thread(r);
thread2.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start the thread only once. You can start a thread again only if thread has completed running.

Below code will not throw any exception:

```
t.start();
if(!t.isAlive()){
   t.start();
 }
```

Comment: You cannot call start twice on a thread, even if it has completed

Answer (score 0):

Once we started a Thread we are not allowed to restart the same Thread otherwise we will get IllegalThreadStateException 
in your code just remove the line

```
 Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
        t.start(); // Remove this line
```

Comment: How is this any different from exexzian's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14901166/369450)?